# Setting creation time attribute on exFAT to "atime" from ext4

Tags: file-system, file-transfer, file-management

I have to move files from my internal storage to the SD Card. While `cp -p` does its job fine to an `ext4` formatted card, moving/copying files to `exFAT` only keeps the file modification time but sets creation to the actual time.

Some of my daily routines on my Windows computer depend on creation time for file sorting etc. To make it even worse, copying from my phone over *MTP* discards [*both* time-stamps](http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html), yielding anything except `jpeg`'s unsortable!

So what I need is just a bit of bash magic which:

1. Reads the atime* of a file/directory
2. Copy the `file/directory` to destination with `cp --preserve t`
3. *Touch* the destination file/dir's *ctime* with the stored one
4. Proceed and recurse
   ???. profit

*Android mounts the storage with noatime/relatime and thus - which I checked myself - atime gives the real creation time here

Comment: Linux kernel doesn't maintain the creation time but only the changed time (ctime), modification time (mtime) and access time (atime) and ctime [can't be changed easily](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36105/105083). So, what is your goal now?

Comment: my goal is co "convert" ext4 atime to "creation time" on exFAT

Comment: But there is no creation time, only changed time.

Comment: yes it has - on Windows. i know what you mean, there is no way to set if from *nix. so, maybe somehow dump all timestamp data to a text file on Android, then parse and feed it to filetouch.exe on Windows?